# Show that $dim(X,\succeq)\leq |X^2|$ when $X$ is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that when $(X,\succeq)$ is a finite preorder, the $dim(X,\succeq)\leq |X^2|$.

Here's the full context (Exercise 11 (a)):

> [image]

My idea of resolution was to show that any set of elements of $X^2$ can be created through the intersection of at most $n^2$ different sets. But since $\succeq$ is reflexive, it already has $n$ elements, namely $(x_1,x_1),\cdots,(x_n,x_n)$, so the number of sets required to make it (through intersections) is less than $n^2-n\leq |X^2|$.

I have two problems, though.

1. Insecurity: I don't know if this idea is correct;
2. Writing: I don't know how to translate that into math.

Can someone give me some help?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking in the right general direction, but you need to look a little closer at how individual pairs of elements of $X$ can behave.

Suppose that $\dim(X,\succeq)=k$, and that $\succeq=R_1\cap\ldots\cap R_k$, where each $R_i$ is a complete preorder extending $\succeq$. Consider a pair $\{x,y\}$ of (not necessarily distinct) elements of $X$.

- If $x\succeq y$ and $y\succeq x$, then both $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,x\rangle$ must belong to every $R_i$.
- If $x\succeq y$ and $y\not\succeq x$, then $\langle x,y\rangle$ must belong to every $R_i$, but there must be at least one $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $\langle y,x\rangle\notin R_i$.
- Similarly, if $x\not\succeq y$ and $y\succeq x$, then $\langle y,x\rangle$ must belong to every $R_i$, but there must be at least one $i$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\notin R_i$.
- Finally, the interesting case is when $x\not\succeq y$ and $y\not\succeq x$. Each $R_i$ must contain at least one of $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,x\rangle$, but neither of these ordered pairs can belong to every $R_i$. Thus, there must be distinct $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_i\setminus R_j$ and $\langle y,x\rangle\in R_j\setminus R_i$.

None of these possibilities requires more than two complete extensions of $\succeq$. In fact, we can start with an $R_1$ that contains every ordered pair that must belong to all of the $R_i$, like the pairs $\langle x,x\rangle$. Then at worst we must add one more total extension for each pair of the second and third types and two more for each pair of the fourth type.

Let $n=|X|$. There are $\binom{n}2=\frac12n(n-1)$ pairs of distinct elements of $X$, so even if all of them are of the fourth type, we need to intersect at most

$$1+2\cdot\frac12n(n-1)=n^2-n+1\le n^2$$

complete extensions of $\succeq$ to get $\succeq$. (I am assuming here that $n\ge 1$.)

Comment: Brian thanks for helping me out! Sorry I took so long to answer =/ I am working on your comments now! Thanks again :D

Comment: @Guilherme: No problem; you’re welcome!

Comment: So in the inequation the first $1$ represents $R_1$ (or the relation $X^2$). The worst case for the 2nd bullet point would be when your relation has both $x\succeq y$ and $y\succeq x$, so that you need another relation R without $y\succeq x$, and the analogous for the 3rd bullet point. For the 4th bullet point, for each $\{(x,y),(y,x)\}\subseteq R_1$ or $X^2$ we need a relation that has $(x,y)$ but not $(y,x)$, and another one with $(y,x)$ but not $(x,y)$. With that you get the first sum of the inequality.  However, that inequality is not valid for $n\neq 1$.

Comment: @Guilherme: The last displayed inequality? It had a bad typo: the righthand side was supposed to be $n^2$, as in the problem. You’re seeing the rest correctly.

Comment: Do you know if there's a counter-example for $dim(X,\succeq)=3$ when $|X|\geq 2$?

Comment: @Guilherme: I’m not sure what you mean here by a counterexample: counterexample to what, exactly?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to show that whenever $|X|\geq 2$, then $dim(X,\succeq)=3$?

Comment: @Guilherme: For any positive integer $n$ let $a_k,b_k$ ($k=1,\ldots,n$) be $2n$ distinct elements, and set $a_k\le b_\ell$ iff $k\ne\ell$. The resulting partial order is of cardinality $2n$ and dimension $n$. See the example in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension).

Comment: Thanks again Brian! I really liked the analysis you made in your answer and I feel that I learned a lot from it!

Comment: @Guilherme: You’re welcome!